# wheelPropagation on a x-scrolling container with perfect-scrollbar

Tags: javascript, perfect-scrollbar

I'm using perfect-scrollbar to scroll large tables on the x-axis. 
When the option `useBothWheelAxes` is set to true I can use the mouse wheel to scroll the table horizontally. When I reach the end of the table, I'd like to keep scrolling down the page. 
Looking at the documentation, I'd expect I can use `wheelPropagation` for this:

> If this option is true, when the scroll reaches the end of the side, mousewheel event will be propagated to parent element.

Vertically this does work. However, this doesn't seem to work when scrolling horizontally.

A demo identifying the problem can be found here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YaXBoV